# Can a car skid while moving in a circle?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, everyday-life, centripetal-force

How can a car skid if it is moving around a circular road? It is understandable that it can topple but I feel it impossible that a moving car can skid.  It is hard to imagine that a car would skid while traversing a circular path.  The wheels of the car are rotating so it seems like a car would topple rather than skid.

Comment: Why not? Image a slick road, like iced surface. Why do you think the tires are not going to skid?

Comment: First of all, define "moving around a circle..." What's the initial vector velocity?  Next, define "skid."  In the Real World (a universe shunned by physicists in favor of spherical cows), it's quite possible for an object to have only partial grip on a surface.  The standard example is a bowling ball which is spinning about its center while rolling down the alley, but the rolling rate is less than required by its longitudinal velocity, so it's sliding as well as rolling.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking whether it is impossible to skid while turnning at all, I have a tree in my front yard (well, my parents' front yard) that says that it is. Just imagine the case where friction goes to zero (for example, there might be a layer of ice on the road.)

If you're asking whether the path will be circular, just note that if you don't move the steering wheel and you maintain a constant speed by applying the right amount gas, then the path must be a circular, since you are moving with constant speed and have a constant curvature (these things are set by amount of gas and steering wheel position, which are constant in time). You can control the radius of curvature by changing the position of the steering wheel. [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MqxxeI6lQPs) (Red Bull drift youtube video) is a youtube video of this happening.

Answer (score 1):

If you understand that a car can topple while negotiating a sharp turn at high speeds, then you just have to consider the fact that skidding happens when the tyres don't have enough grip to prevent the car from being thrown out the trajectory. Newton first law states that any solid tends to continue in a straight path, so the solid has to be pulled perpendicularly to its velocity in order to go in a circle. On a car this force is created by the friction of the tyres on the ground: it effectively "pushes" on the ground when oriented toward the inside of the turn. Toppling happens because of this force: the centrifugal force acting on the centre of gravity (from the fact the solid can't go straight and has to follow another path), above the ground obviously, yields to a torque about the contact line of the outer set of wheels. If you don't have grip for example on a frozen puddle, the car doesn't topple, it slips. On the road, there is a partial grip that detaches rubber from the tyre.